# Method Call in Different Class

Tags: java, class, interface, hierarchy, abstract

This is my first post, so please forgive me for my mistakes. I currently have a class `EventGenerator` that calls a method in another class `Top` through an interface `Event`. I want to create subclasses say `B`, `C`, `D` that extend `Top` so they have similar properties of `Top`. Each of these subclasses should function like `Top` so that they each get a method called each time `EventGenerator` calls the method. However, **I do not want there to modify** `EventGenerator` or `Top`, so that the subclasses are **independent**, and **do not need to be instantiated** in 'EventGenerator' or `Top`. Is this even possible? Ideally, I would make `Top` an **abstract** class.  Does my question make sense? Thank you very much for all your help.

```
public class Top implements Event {

    public void update(int a) {out.println(a);}

}
```

Event Generator calls update in Top

```
Top t = new Top();
public class EventGenerator {
    public void run() {
       update(t, 3);
    }
    public void update(Event e, int a) {
       e.update(a);
    }
}
```

Through the interface

```
public interface Event {
   update(int i);
}
```

Comment: Well, your code contains the solution. EventGenerator doesn't instantiate any Event, and calls a method on it. So, what's the problem? All you need in EventGenerator (which is badly named, since it doesn't generate events) is a constructor or method that receives an Event to update as argument.

Comment: I assume you mean `t.update(3);` In Java 8 you might make `Top` an interface.  Only you can answer whether it makes sense or not.

Comment: sounds like the Listener pattern for me

Comment: Hey @JBNizet first thanks for your timely response, putting in the constructor makes a lot of sense. I apologize for the poor naming convention, I was trying to simplify the overall problem that I was having.